# why cookie delete not working on my server but working fine on my local system?

Tags: php, cookies

The cookie is not deleting on my Debian apache server but deleting fine on my local xampp.
Here is the code i used for setting cookie

```
$token = substr(hash('sha512', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 50);
$extime =  time()+86500;

$url_parts = parse_url(current_url());
$domain = str_replace('www.', '', $url_parts['host']);

// set cookie

setcookie('rememberme',$token,$extime,"/",$domain);
```

This code works on the server and rememberme cookie is created on the server.

Here is the code I used for deleting it

```
// Delete Cookie
setcookie('rememberme',"",0,"/");
```

The above code work fine on local but not working on my server.

I hosted the test application as subdomain with url like http://example.com/myproject and $domain give value `.example.com`

If someone knows why it not working properly on server please help me.

Comment: Expire date has to be in the past

Comment: You realise that the cookie in the browser is not effected until you send a page to the browser so the new cookie information i.e. the delete gets sent to the browser

Comment: setcookie('rememberme','',time()-3600);

Comment: For my information: Is a zero not considered to be in the past?

Comment: Using `0` as the 3rd parameter (`$expire`) means the cookie is to be stored until the browser is closed. (See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php))

Comment: @ccKep Ah yes of course, silly me!

Comment: @RiggsFolly  The manual states: If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

Comment: @Kaylined Yup See previous 2 comments I remember now

Comment: @Kaylined i tried setcookie('rememberme','',time()-3600); but no effect on server

Comment: what about `setcookie('rememberme',"",0,"/",$domain);` ? many a times, it needs the domain. Anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: (and add the domain as an argument).

```
setcookie('rememberme',"",0,"/",$domain);
```

Many a times, it needs the domain.

From the manual on cookies: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php and from User Contributed Notes:

*"if you are having problems seeing cookies sometimes or deleting cookies sometimes, despite following the advice below, make sure you are setting the cookie with the domain argument. Set it with the dot before the domain as the examples show: ".example.com".  I wasn't specifying the domain, and finally realized I was setting the cookie when the browser url had the http://www.example.com and later trying to delete it when the url didn't have the www. ie. http://example.com. This also caused the page to be unable to find the cookie when the www. wasn't in the domain.  (When you add the domain argument to the setcookie code that creates the cookie, make sure you also add it to the code that deletes the cookie.)"*

Comment: Thank you sir for the detail explanation.

Comment: @GeordyJames You're most welcome Geordy. I felt it needed more information, rather than just popping in a quick answer, *cheers*